# applying Neyman-Pearson Lemma

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Suppose that we have a random sample $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ from a prob function with density: $$
f(x) = 3\theta^3x^{-4} 
$$
given that $x\geq \theta$

Now the question is

> use Neyman-Pearson's Lemma to find a most powerful test for testing $H_0:\theta =4$ against $H_a : \theta = 3$

Now I keep getting into trouble with Neyman-Pearson. So If anybody could give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong, that'd be great.

The combined PDF is defined as:
$$
f_\bar{x}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(3\theta^3)^n \prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{-4}I_{(\theta,\infty)}(x_i)
$$
As far as I know.
Now implementing this witht he two thetas I get:
$$
\begin{equation}
\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{(3\times4^3)^n \prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{-4}I_{(4,\infty)}(x_i)}{(3\times 3^3)^n \prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{-4}I_{(3,\infty)}(x_i)} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$

Now my book says the formula is
$$
\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\dfrac{f(x_1,\dots,x_n;\theta_0)}{f(x_1,\dots,x_n;\theta_a)}
$$
and they say let $C^*$ be the set
$$
C^* = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n)|\lambda (x_1,\dots,x_n;\theta_0,\theta_a)\leq k\}
$$
So essentially they're saying, $C^*$ is the critical region for which the $\lambda$ fraction is less than a certain $k$, for which k is defined as a constant such that:
$$
P[(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in C^*|\theta_0]=\alpha
$$

Now as was suggested I drew $(1)$. for $n=1$, so taking $f_0(x)=81x^{-4}I_{(3,\infty)}(x)$ and $f_1(x)=3\times 64x^{-4}I_{(4,\infty)}(x)$ we get:
$$
\dfrac{81x^{-4}}{3\times 64x^{-4}}I_{(4,\infty)}(x)
$$
However, because the $x^{-4}$ cancel out I just get $\dfrac{27}{64}$. so taking the integral from $4 \to \infty$ gives me $\infty$.

In the general case for $n\to\infty$
$$
L(\theta) = \infty I_{(3,4)} + \underbrace{ \frac{27}{64} I_{(4,\infty)}}_{\text{what does this tell me?}}
$$

Comment: are ur samples independent? and note that the area under your densities should be $1$.

Comment: I'm assuming yes. This is never stated but in our exercises it mostly holds.  yeah its 0 if x is less than $\theta$

Comment: I think there is a problem here. you can simply insert $3$ and then $4$ and take the integral from $0$ to $\infty$. The results both should be $1$ which is not possible. Either you have an integration upto some $k<\infty$, which is determined such that the area is $1$ or you need some extra information in your question.

Comment: only extra thing I can get is $\theta > 0$. I really dont know how to tackle this.

Comment: ohh just a second. You have another condition which is $x\geq \theta$. This is what I am talking about...

Comment: ah.. yes, given that , the integral of the pdf is 1. from $\theta$ to $\infty$, thats why i have the indicator in my function.

Comment: Okay now it is clear. You must add $u(x-\theta)$ to the end of your equation. More specifically, $u(x-\theta_0)$ when the null hypothesis is correct, else $u(x-\theta_1)$ when the alternative is correct. Then your likelihood will be dependent on $x$

Comment: okay clear. so $I$ was indicator function. I was thinking that it was another function as i use $\mathbf 1$ for that.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was how you write it out. what exactly is $u(x-\theta)$?

Comment: check in google "heviside step function"

Comment: Not really sure how it helps me :(

Comment: draw the densities for $n=1$ and see with your eyes what is happening when $n=1$, then think what will happen when $n>1$

Comment: You will not take the integral of the likelihood function. You will use the likelihood to decide for the threshold. For example if your thereshold is $c$ then you will take $\alpha=\int_{\{x:L(x)>c\}}f_0(x)$

Comment: One more thing: your $L(x)=\infty I_{(3,4)}+(27/64) I_{(4,\infty)}$

Comment: really having trouble seeing the relationship between likelihood, threshold  most powerful test. ,I can see two lines going down. What does the combined fraction tell me?

Comment: assume $c=(27/64)+0.001$ then what is your $\alpha$? and when $c=(27/64)-0.001$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9224/discussion-between-wisestrawberry-and-seyhmus-gungoren)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First of all to calculate the likehood funtion, you have multiplication not the summation. Second $I(\theta,\infty)$ in your last formula is incorret. In the nominator it should read $I(\theta_1,\infty)$ and in the denominator $I(\theta_0,\infty)$, where $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are $4$ and $3$ respectively.

Then take for simplicity, $n=1$. Now you have two simple hypothesis. Answer the following questions: "what decision should you give if $3<x<4$" and where should you put the threshold to get a specific false alarm rate?.

Then let $n\neq 1$, how does your densities look like and eventually what is the distribution of your likelihood function under the $H_0$ and $H_1$. From there you need to integrate the distribution of the likelihood under $H_0$ from some thereshold to $\infty$ which will give you some $\alpha$, that is your false alarm rate. This threshold will also maximize your detection rate.

Comment: a few remarks that I don't understand, if I use $n=1$ I get $$
\dfrac{4^3I_{(4,\infty)}(x_1)}{3^3I_{(3,\infty)}(x_1)} \leq k
$$
what do you mean with the threshold to get a specific false alarm rate? Threshold for which variable? $x$?

Comment: draw the densities on a piece of paper and think for which $x$ should you decide for $H_0$ and for which decide for $H_1$

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: didnt even see that I used product and not summation. So i get the likelihood function of both distributions and check for which of the theta's I get the the highest likelihood for it to be the 'correct' theta?

Comment: Yes you can interpret like this.

Comment: im getting $\infty$ for both.

Comment: no please seperate your densities for the **case_1**: $3<x<4$ and **case_2**: $x\geq 4$. Then for **case_1** you will get $\infty$. That is correct but for  the case $x\geq 4$ you will not get $\infty$. What does it mean then if you get $\infty$ when $3<x<4$?

Comment: just checking: is the pdf im getting even correct?
$$
f(x;\theta) = n\log(3) +n3\log(\theta)-4\sum \log(x_i)
$$

Comment: forget about $\theta$ it is already given. $f_1(x)=81x^{-4}I(3,\infty)$ and $f_0(x)=3*64x^{-4}I(4,\infty)$ for $n=1$ but one needs to check if both have area $1$ or not. Then when you draw them for $x\geq 4$ what do you see.

Comment: Oh, I was drawing them for [3,4]. Alright let me check.

Comment: I'm getting $1$ for $f_0(x)$. What is that telling me? That $H_0$ is better? Thanks for all the input btw! Really helping me understand the problem :)

Comment: $81x^{-4}/192x^{-4}I(4,\infty)=1$ how do you get it?

Comment: I think I'll make a new question with everything I know so far. I'm missing some key elements I think

Comment: No you are on the right tract but it is your decision of course. You could also add your drawings and share your ideas..

Comment: Ill update my original post, with my drawings and ideas.

Comment: It will be great. The problem is though easy, you will learn much better in this way. Dont take anything as negative, i will help you further.